# Why is alt V dragging from the bottom rather than the top

Tags: modeling

I'm watching a tutorial on how to make a head in blender.  To make a nose the person is using alt v to extrude the vertices.  I'm clicking above the vertice I have selected like she says, but it drags from the bottom.  The first image shows how its supposed to look and the second shows what's happening to me.  Any help would be appreciated[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to put your mouse cursor where you're supposed to move your vertex afterwards, maybe it's your problem here?

Comment: yeah that's what I thought but I have it above above the vertex... :(

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=900ZnRKn" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/900ZnRKn/)

Comment: thank u!  now the vertices isn't letting me select it at all  sadly

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping vertices, select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*. Also deactivate the *Proportional Editing* option.